# L Hopital's rule - If $\frac{\cos (t \log c) c^{1-\sigma}}{ \cos (t \log c) c^{\sigma} }=1$ where , $c>1$ Prove that $\sigma=1/2$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, derivatives

If $\frac{\cos (t \log c) c^{1-\sigma}}{ \cos (t \log c) c^{\sigma} 
 }$=1 where , c$>1$ and 0$<$$\sigma$ $<$1

Prove that $\sigma$=1/2.

If $\cos(t \ln c)\neq$0 then $c^{1-2\sigma}=1$

$(1-2\sigma$)log c=0

$c> 1$ so log $c >$0

$\sigma=1/2$.

If $\cos (t \log c)=0$

$$\lim_{t\to\ (2n+1)\pi/(2 \log  c)}   \frac{\cos (t \log c) c^{1-\sigma}}{ \cos (t \log c) c^{\sigma} 
 }=1
  $$
Applying L-Hopital's Rule,

$$\lim_{t\to (2n+1)\pi/(2 \log  c)}   \frac{\log  c  \sin (t \log c) c^{1-\sigma}}{\log  c \sin (t \log c) c^{\sigma} 
 }=1
  $$
log  $c>0$ since $c>1$

Implies $c^{1-2\sigma}=1$

$\sigma=1/2$ since $c>1$.
Is every step correct?.

Comment: @Paul Enta is there any mistake??

Comment: I just tried to improve formatting for readability of the question.

Comment: @Paul Enta Is every step correct?

Comment: @Paul Enta please upvote my question.